# How to do a substring in PHP?

Tags: php, substring

I have this project in PHP, and I need to get rid of the "0" at start.

This the line of code I have that already takes of all the letters and keeps all the numbers.

```
$Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getValue()));
```

The output will be = "0123004567" I want to remove the first number "0" with substring(Like in java). Can you show me how to do it in PHP?

Comment: @mistermartin drop the third parameter, just `substr($Number,1);`

Answer (score 5):

The function you're looking for is

```
$Number = ltrim($Number,'0');
```

That will only remove zeroes at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know PHP even had such a function.

Comment: Can you put that in the context of the expression I have?

Comment: this will take off all the leading zeroes. if you just want the first character off, its substr($Number, 1);